# mysql search query syntax using a php $variable

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble with the $message part of my MYSQL query.

```
$sql = 'SELECT message_time FROM ' . MCHAT_TABLE . ' 
        WHERE user_id = ' . (int) $user->data['user_id'] . ', message = '$message'
        ORDER BY message_time DESC'; Any help with the syntax would be appreciated. If I remove , message = '$message' the query returns no errors.


    // Flood control

$message = 'I have opened Video Chat. <strong>(Automated Message)</strong> ';
$mchat_flood_current_time = time(); 
echo $mchat_flood_current_time;
echo " ";
echo $user->data['user_id'];

$sql = 'SELECT message_time FROM ' . MCHAT_TABLE . ' 
        WHERE user_id = ' . (int) $user->data['user_id'] . ', message = '$message'
        ORDER BY message_time DESC';
$result = $db->sql_query_limit($sql, 1);
$row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result);
$db->sql_freeresult($result);
echo " ";
echo $row['message_time'];
echo " ";
echo ($mchat_flood_current_time - $row['message_time']);
if($row['message_time'] >= 0 && ($mchat_flood_current_time - $row['message_time']) > 30)
{
```

Comment: Assuming `$message` is a string, it needs to be quoted. And you need to fix your concatenation.

Comment: In the WHERE part you should use AND between parts not ,-character

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT message_time FROM " . MCHAT_TABLE . " WHERE user_id = " . (int) $user->data['user_id'] . " AND message = '" . $message . "' ORDER BY message_time DESC';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the message variable in quotes and replace the comma before "message =" with AND so your query looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT message_time FROM " . MCHAT_TABLE . " 
WHERE user_id = " . (int) $user->data['user_id'] . " 
AND message = '" . $message . "' 
ORDER BY message_time DESC";
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I truly appreciate it and will upvote the answer.

Comment: For some reason I can't I clicked "Accept the answer" Thank you again!